# Удаление пункта в классе адаптера

Tags: android, listview, listener

Есть `listView`. Есть база данных. Есть иконка с крестиком в пункте. Есть `alert`, который вызывается по крестику. Удаление происходит в классе адаптера. В классе активити есть свой слушатель нажатия на итем и выполняет он другую задачу. Код в классе адаптера.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.textView1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COL_NAME_NOTE)));
    holder.textView2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COL_NOTE)));
    holder.textView3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COL_DATE)));
    holder.linearItem.setBackgroundColor(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COL_COLOR)));
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("TAG", "clicked in adapter");
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Удаление...");
            alert.setMessage("Вы уверены?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                    dh.delNote(getItemId(...?...));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
}
```

Чтобы удалить конкретно нужную запись, нужно передать в параметр нужный Id(позицию), как получить нужную позицию?

В `imageView` картинка с крестиком.

Метод удаления в классе бд

```
public void delNote(int id){
    getReadableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = " +id, null);
}
```

Comment: вы можете модифицировать метод, `bindView`, передав в него номер позиции как final параметр, после чего его можно будет получить в методе удаления. Не оформляю ответ, т.к. выглядит костыльновато, может у кого-то есть более красивое решение.

Comment: А как правильно этот метод модифицировать. Добавил в параметр `final int position` и студия стала говорить, что, что - то не так

Comment: Мне понравилась идея с модифицированием метода `bindView `, только как его правильно модифицировать, студия ругается, просит заново имплементировать его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
final int itemId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

....

alert.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
           dh.delNote(itemId);
           cursor.requery();
           notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
});
```